# React Native: When accessing a component via ref, how do you access methods of that component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-ref

In my React Native app, I have a component `Form1`:

```
class Form1 extends Component {
  function1 = () => {...}
  render() {return(...)}
}
```

In `Form1` I can access `function1` via `this.function1()`. I create an instance of `Form1` in another component and pass it the prop `var1`, which I can access in `Form1` via `this.props.var1`.

```
<Form1
  ref={ref => {this.form = ref.wrappedInstance}}
  var1="hello"
/>
```

Here where I set `this.form = ref.wrappedInstance` in the parent component, I can then access `var1` via `this.form.props.var1`. In other words, `ref.wrappedInstance.props` exists. However, I can't access `function1` the same way; `ref.wrappedInstance.function1` *doesn't* exist.

How can I access `function1` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Refs have to be forwarded outside of normal props. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html for instructions on how to forward a ref and build a component to accept that ref.